# How can I increment and decrement the fontsize via shortcut? (tinymce)

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, font-size

I want to increment and decrement the fontsize like in microsoft word.
I need one shortcut to increment and one to decrement.
Currently I have this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('ds_fontsize', function (editor, url) {
editor.addMenuItem('fontsize_up', {
    text: 'fontsize_up',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand('fontsize_up');
    }

});

editor.addMenuItem('fontsize_down', {
    text: 'fontsize-down',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand('fontsize_down');
    }

});

editor.addCommand('fontsize_down', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("px", 1)
    fontsize--;

    //remove old span
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, '', 'span');
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.create('span', { style: 'font-size: 15px' }, content));
});

editor.addCommand('fontsize_up', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("px", 1)
    fontsize++;

    //remove old span
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, '', 'span');
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.create('span', { style: 'font-size:' + fontsize + 'px' }, content));
}); 
});
```

Ok this works mainly, but if I increment or decrement more then one size the old span wouldn't remove.
I get HTML-Code like this:

```
<p><span style="font-size:12px"><span style="font-size:13px">Hello World</span></span></p>
```

Does anyone have a solution for me or an other way to do this?

Thanks Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution! :)
The tinymce editor have an implemented function to set the fontsize, but you can`t find in the documentation.
Search here "fontsize": https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/classes/EditorCommands.js#L253 -> Line 253

And here is my code:

```
tinymce.init({
...

setup: function (editor) {
//initialize shortcuts
editor.on('keydown', function (e) {
     //decrement fontsize
     if (e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 226) {
         e.preventDefault();
         editor.execCommand("fontsize_down");
     }
     //increment fontsize
     if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 226) {
         e.preventDefault();
         editor.execCommand("fontsize_up");
     }
});
}
});
```

And here is my plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('ds_fontsize', function (editor, url) {
editor.addMenuItem('fontsize_up', {
    text: 'fontsize_up',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand('fontsize_up');
    }

});

editor.addMenuItem('fontsize_down', {
    text: 'fontsize-down',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand('fontsize_down');
    }

});

editor.addCommand('fontsize_down', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("px", 1)
    fontsize--;

    if (fontsize > 7 && fontsize <=72) {
        switch (fontsize) {
            case 35:
                fontsize = 28;
                break;
            case 47:
                fontsize = 36;
                break;
            case 71:
                fontsize = 48;
                break;
            default:
                if (fontsize > 12) fontsize--;
        }
        fontsize = fontsize + "px";
        alert(fontsize);
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);
    }
});

editor.addCommand('fontsize_up', function () {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

    fontsize = fontsize.split("px", 1)
    fontsize++;

    if (fontsize > 7 && fontsize <= 72) {
        switch (fontsize) {
            case 29:
                fontsize = 36;
                break;
            case 37:
                fontsize = 48;
                break;
            case 49:
                fontsize = 72;
                break;
            default:
                if (fontsize > 12) fontsize++;
        }
        fontsize = fontsize + "px";
        alert(fontsize);
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);
    }
}); 
});
```

I hope it is useful for someone. :)
Greetings Felix